# Node js port is already in use

Tags: node.js, process, localhost, port, web-hosting

When I start my webserver, node throws `listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`, I tried to use netstat and search for 3000 port (or another, it happens with any port), but nothing found. Also no node processes in task manager, no webpage on `localhost:3000`. Also I tried to reload windows, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you provide the full log of the NodeJS process? The js code too would be helpful

Comment: log https://pastebin.com/MDUELSqy, code https://pastebin.com/siLUgtpC

Comment: do `sudo netstat -npl | grep 3000` . netstat without sudo would not show you processes you don't own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code you are trying to bind the socket module to port 3000:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
/* ... */
app.listen(3000);
```

in this way when the server tries to bind itself the port is already `in use`.

You have to create the HTTP server and then bind the socket.io module on it:

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

(taken from the socket.io documentation)

Comment: @Iaiao in that way you are only changing the port. Please refer to the documentation and bind it to the server itself...

Answer (score 2):

use the command to kill the process on port

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows 10, I would recommend trying Resource Monitor. The Network tab has a view called Listening Ports, which should tell you which process is using port 3000

[Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohCed.png)

Comment: I don't see 3000 port there. Ports are the same as in cmd netstat

Answer (score 0):

The port is currently occupied by other tasks. You need to stop them using the following commands. The first command will show you the process ID (PID) that is running on the port, which you can then use to stop the process with the second command:

$sudo netstat -nltp | grep (Put here Running port)

$sudo kill -9 (Put Here Process ID you got)

Please replace  with the specific port number and  with the process ID you want to terminate.